# Error in LInking service and directive in Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-service

I have an issue at linking service having http to a directive. This is the code of that...

```
    myapp.factory ( 'autoCompleteDataService', ['$http', function($http) {
   return {
       getSource: function(callback) {
          var url = 'get_data_from_server.php';
          $http.get(url).success(function(data) {
             callback(data);
          });
       }
   }
} ] );

myapp.directive('autoComplete', function(autoCompleteDataService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
            elem.autocomplete({
                source: autoCompleteDataService.getSource(), 
                select: function( event, ui ) {
                         scope.$apply(function() {
                           scope.item.unit_id = ui.item.value; 
                         });
                        },
                minLength: 2
            });
        }
    };
});
```

I replaced `callback(data);` with `return data;` with no result...

Any help is appreciated..

Edit: added working code without http

If I keep this code instead the above one its working

```
myapp.factory('autoCompleteDataService', [function() {
return {
    getSource: function() {
        return ['apples', 'oranges', 'bananas'];
    }
}
```

}]);

Comment: your autocomplete function on the element is done by a plugin or something else ?

Comment: @Thomas by a standard jui ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
myapp.factory('autoCompleteDataService', ['$http', function($http) {
    return {
        getSource: function() {
            var url = 'get_data_from_server.php';
            return $http.get(url);
        }
    }
}]);
```

Directive:

```
link : function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
    autoCompleteDataService.getSource().success(function(data) {
        elem.autocomplete({
            source: data, 
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                scope.$apply(function() { scope.item.unit_id = ui.item.value; });
            },
            change: function (event, ui) {
                if (ui.item === null) {
                    scope.$apply(function() { scope.foo = null });
                }
            },
            minLength: 2
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Sorry Its not working... SyntaxError: Unexpected token '
    at Object.parse (native)
    at qb (http://localhost/gis/angular/angular.min.js:13:147)
    at Zc.d.defaults.transformResponse (http://localhost/gis/angular/angular.min.js:93:99)
    at http://localhost/gis/angular/angular.min.js:92:421
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at m (http://localhost/gis/angular/angular.min.js:6:192)
    at Sb (http://localhost/gis/angular/angular.min.js:92:403)
    at c (http://localhost/gis/angular/angular.min.js:94:87)
    at h (http://localhost/gis/angular/angular.min.js:78:207)

Comment: I have offered a totally different solution. Have a look at my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but same error. I cant judge where is the root cause of this error, in the directive or @ service.

Comment: Changed output of server php reply from echo "['apples', 'oranges', 'bananas']"; to echo (json_encode(array('apple','ornage','bananas'))); Now the last syntax error issue resolved, and loaded without error. When typing in input box I got error from jqueryui script as                Uncaught TypeError: Property 'source' of object [object Object] is not a function jquery-ui-1.10.3.js:6214
$.widget._search jquery-ui-1.10.3.js:6214
(anonymous function) jquery-ui-1.10.3.js:401
$.widget.search jquery-ui-1.10.3.js:6206
(anonymous function) jquery-ui-1.10.3.js:401....
Any Idea where the issue is??

Comment: I am accepting your answer bcoz i feel its ok in angular part, and fault in jui ... i think..

Answer (score 1):

Another way to answer the issue,, with full filtering logic at server side..

```
    myapp.directive('autoComplete', function(autoCompleteDataService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',

        link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {

            elem.autocomplete({

                source: function( request, response ) {
                            $.ajax({
                              url: "./get_data_from_server.php",
                              dataType: "json",
                              data: {
                                maxRows: 10,
                                startsWith: request.term
                              },
                              success: function( data ) {
                                  response(data);
                              }
                            });
                          },

                select: function( event, ui ) {
            scope.$apply(function() { scope.item.unit_id = ui.item.value; });
                },

                minLength: 2
            });
        }

    };
 });
```